# I see a character called xDB on notepad++. What character is this?

Tags: regex, vb.net, notepad++, control-characters, programmers-notepad

[What is this character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NT9W.jpg)

All I really need to know is what is this character. I have not seen anything like this before.

How do i remove this using Vb.net:

data = data.Replace(Chr(???????), "")

Is there a specific control character decimal number or something to this character that i can use in place of ??
Please help.

I tried looking up all the html, ascii and the regex languages to find this character but i did not find this anywhere.

Comment: `\xDB` is the `Û` character.

Comment: In the Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1 extended ASCII character sets, the character is a uppercase U with circumflex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent possible bugs related to the encoding of your source files, you should use a hex editor (such as [this Notepad++ plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/)) to find the hexadecimal code of the character, then use that to reference the character in your code:

```
data = data.Replace((char)0xDB, "")
```

as opposed to:

```
data = data.Replace("Û", "")
```

Note: In this case the hex editor is unnecessary because xDB is already a hex code, but other control characters, such as `CR` and `LF`, are not displayed as their hex values [in Notepad++].